# Adjust list to follow natural flow

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a normal `ul>li` list inside a container like this

```
<div class='conatiner'>
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want the flow to be adjusted as you can see in the following figure. Not sure whether its even possible. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gk59dorL/1/)

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Even if I do the `order` thing, I cannot add rows in between no?

Comment: The most contesting thing on this case is to make it responsive. Sometimes 3 listpoints fit in one row, sometimes 4 or just 2. To set absolute order attributes don't do the trick here!

Comment: @Flo may be I can live with a `fixed number of items` in a `row`

Comment: It's not a big deal with a <div> structure or several <ul>, if you're okay with that?

Comment: @Flo my intention was to get this thing working with normal list, but I am looking for other option since I am not getting a proper resolution. :(

Comment: The duplicate has both a CSS and a script solution

Comment: @LGSon my bad, the answer was linked in the top of the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lis = $("ul > li");
  for(var i = 3; i < lis.length; i+=6) {
    lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='y'></div>");
  }
})
```

```css
.conatiner {
  width: 250px;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}

.conatiner:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block; 
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(250px/3);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.y li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='conatiner'>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this one with just one `<ul>` isn't possible without doing css hacks with `order` attributes and a lot of hard coded lines.

But there are two different and easy alternatives!

First one - use several `<ul>`! One `<ul>` contains a max number of 3 `<li>` (or how many you ever want in one row).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul:nth-of-type(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

You set one ul-reverted and one non-reverted class. Both are displayed flex. The list-style of the reverted one is, surprise - row-reverted.

Alternative 2 is the same structure just with `<div>` containers. Works the same way!

Comment: This can be further improved by doing `ul:nth-of-type(even)` for the `row-reverse`, getting rid of the need for a class.

Comment: That's right, but it's not faster in the brwosers rendering then class assignments.

Comment: The performance effect would be negligible with only a few elements.

Comment: Okay, that is true. But to not set classes is just a point when there are not any other <ul> in a different context.